# Python: Best way to decorate a function only locally

Tags: python, python-decorators

What is the best way to decorate a function, but only in a local scope. For example we have the following:

```
def a():
    do stuff
    b()
    do stuff
```

I want to make a function `c()` that does the same `stuff` but decorates b so it adds some extra stuff. I found a way to do that but it changes b() globally:

```
def c():
    global b
    b = decorator(b)
    a()
```

Is there a way to do that but without changing the function b globally?

Comment: `b = decorator(b)` - I think this is overriding your global function `b`. Maybe assigning it to another variable is what you are looking for: `x = decorator(b)`.

Comment: Can not be x, because I want to have different b function inside c() so when I call a() inside c(), a() is different but only when I call it inside c()

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the function `b`, and replace it with another function. Use `unittest.mock` in Python 3, or `mock` in Python 2 for this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def c():
    with patch('b', decorator(b)):
        a()

# Or, as a decorator
@patch('b', decorator(b))
def c():
    a()
```

By patching, you're essentially replacing the `b` instance with your own.

Comment: It works, but you  have to install mock. And it seems that there is an issue with mock when it tries to install six (the issue seems very common)

Comment: Yeah, though `mock` is a part of standard library in Python 3. I am not aware of issue while installing `six` and `mock` in Py 2.7 though.

Answer (score 1):

Python allow any object to be a callable, not only functions.

You could use something like:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, func=b):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self):
        # do stuff
        self.func()
        # do other stuff
```

Then with `a = A()`, `a()` will simply invoke `f` but if you write`c = A(decorator(b))`, `c()` will invoke the decorated version

Answer (score 1):

Since you're rebinding `b()` so that calling `a()` will respect the updated `b()`, you can save the original `b()`, and restore it afterwards. This may not be the most efficient way, but it worked for me.

```
import copy
def c():
    global b
    orig_b = copy.deepcopy(b)
    b = decorator(b)
    a()
    b = orig_b
```